# How do I pass a Generic::List by reference?

Tags: c++, .net, pass-by-reference, argument-passing

In an attempt to wrap some unmanaged code in a managed .dll I'm trying to convert a `Generic::List` of data points into a `std::vector`. Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
namespace ManagedDLL
{
    public ref class CppClass
    {
        void ListToStdVec( const List<double>& input_list, std::vector<double>& output_vector )
        {
            // Copy the contents of the input list into the vector
            // ...
        }

        void ProcessData( List<double> sampleData )
        {
            std::vector<double> myVec;

            ListToStdVec( sampleData, myVec );

            // Now call the unmanaged code with the new vector
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this gives me:

> error C3699: '&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'const System::Collections::Generic::List'

I've probably missed something fundamental here (I'm relatively new to .net's way of doing things), but that looks like reasonably valid code to me.. ?

**[Edit]** I've tried both Andy and Dario's suggestions and they work, but how do I then access the members of the input list? I've tried all sorts of combinations of dreferencing and nothing seems to compile:

```
void ListToStdVec( const List<double>% input_list, std::vector<double>& output_vector )
{
    int num_of_elements = input_list->Count;
}

void ListToStdVec( const List<double>^ input_list, std::vector<double>& output_vector )
{
    int num_of_elements = input_list.Count;
}
```

...both give me:

> error C2662: 'System::Collections::Generic::List::Count::get' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const System::Collections::Generic::List' to 'System::Collections::Generic::List %'

...so how do you access the reference / pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `List<T>` is a managed .NET class, it's passed by managed GC-Handle denoted by ^ and not by C++-reference.

Ex:

```
void ListToVec(List<double>^ input_list, std::vector<double>& out)
```

You don't need additional `const` here. The notation `List<T>^%` creates a tracking reference (comparable to C++-pointers) rather than a call by reference.
Just access the members by `list->...` and `list[...]`.

Comment: Removing the const does indeed allow me to access input_list's members, but I like to make inputs const wherever possible as it often catches mistakes at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Herb Sutter](http://blogs.msdn.com/hsutter/archive/2004/07/31/203131.aspx), `%` is the managed object pass by reference character. Convert the code to the following, and it should work:

```
void ListToStdVec( const List<double>% input_list, std::vector<double>& output_vector
{
    // Copy the contents of the input list into the vector
    // ...
}
```

**Edit**: I think the `const` is causing the issues, although I'm not sure why. If you change the `List` argument to not be `const`, then the first function will compile if you use the `->` operator, while the second function will compile if you use the `.` operator (I'm not sure why that difference exists - it doesn't make much sense).

That said, if all that you want to do is to copy the elements in the `List` to the `vector`, then you really want to use `^`. Think of that as having a reference to the managed object. I think that `%` would be used if you want to pass the reference "by reference" (i.e. reassign `input_list` to something else within `ListToStdVec()`, and have the caller see the result of that assignment. However, given that you use the `.` operator to access members when using `%`, that tells me that I may not understand the purpose of that at all.

Comment: If that's true the why does input_list->Count work for the ^ operator and input_list.Count work for the % operator? Tradionally that would indicate the opposite (speaking from a C++ perspective)?

Comment: r.e. your edit; I'd come to the same conclusion and am just as mistified :-)